# Загрузка данных с помощью Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, localhost, javascript

Есть страница, на которой расположено огромное количество ссылок, ведущих на разные разделы этой страницы. Ссылки -- это блоки с id типа:

```
<div class="link" id="page=edit&rub=make">Ссылка</div>
```

При нажатии на такой блок, ajax'ом данные передаются обратно в этот php-файл и страница полностью обновляется. Что-то вроде:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   jQuery.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'page.php',
      data: {'id':id},
   success:function(html){
      $('body').html(html);
   }
  });
});
```

На localhost всё работает отлично, но после загрузки на сайт всё стало очень сильно тормозить -- страница обновляется через 1-3 секунды. Скажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: может вся проблема в хостинге?
сколько эта страница изначально загружается если набрать 'page.php' в браузере?

Comment: ХЗ. Я уже сменил всё на обычные ссылки типа < a href="" > -- стало работать на порядок быстрее. Но я всегда знал, что на хостингере лучше не сидеть...